# How do I submit a JSON encoded post request from an HTML form?

Tags: html, json

Currently I'm trying to send a post request to a server I have, which is configured to only accept JSON data.

Unfortunately, when I inspect the post request through the developer console of my browser, it sends the data not encoded as JSON, but as an encoded url so the response is of type 415, due to the discrepancy between expected type and provided data.

The form:

```
<form action='http://myhost.elasticbeanstalk.com/API/Beta/Register' method = 'post' enctype='application/json'>
 Email: *<br>
 <input  type='text' name='Email' style='width: 500px;'  value='{"Email":"test@gmail.com"}'><br>
<br>
(Fields denoted with * are mandatory)
<br>
<input type='submit' value='Apply' style='float: right;'>
</form>
```

As you can see, I should in theory send a request of content type json, however if you examine the request that gets sent, you see that the content type remains as an encoded url, yet the tag "enctype='application/json'" should fix that unless I'm mistaken.
(imgur is currently down, as usual, so I'll change this image to a more permanent link when possible)
https://puu.sh/unXtf/2610742d2f.png

Am I missing something?

Comment: `{"Email":"test@gmail.com"}` should just be `test@gmail.com`

Comment: That isn't the issue currently, as the issue is that it is not being encoded as json either way. If you change it to raw text and not a json formatted string, it's still url encoded which is an issue. I'll obviously need to change it in a bit once I have this issue resolved, but since the server is expecting json and it's receiving url encoded data, this is what causes the 415 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers natively do not support JSON as a media type with HTML. Use XMLHttpRequest/Ajax to submit your form as JSON. Dummy example using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'http://yoururl',
          type: 'POST',
          data: yourFormDataSearilized
          contentType: 'application/json', // this is what you want
          success: function() {
            // check
          }
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately since this is using a basic web page builder so I can have a temporary page while the actual site is being developed, I don't have the luxury of being able to use anything like that. However, in that case I shall resort to another method that doesn't rely on JSON at this time. Thanks.